# Planar Motion of Dyanamical System

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-analysis

Given the system

$ \dot x = y^2 - z^2 + xy $

$ \dot y = 2x^2 - y^2 - xz $

$ \dot z = 2z^2 - 4x^2 - 2xy + 2xz $

how do I show that the motion of this system is along a plane and what can I say about its long term behavior?

First, the obvious fixed point where $ \dot x = \dot y = \dot z = 0$ is at the point $(0,0,0)$. The eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix evaluated at this point are just $ λ=0$, so the fixed point is stable. This is fine, but I'm unsure how to prove that this system's motion lies on a plane.

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ lies in a plane then there are numbers $a,b,c$ such that $ax(t) + by(t) + cz(y) = $ constant. Take the derivative and use the ODE to get an equation system for $a,b,c$: $0 = 2(b-2c)x^2 + (a-b)y^2 + (-a+2c)z^2 + (a-2c)xy + (-b+2c)xz = 0$. Note that we require all the coefficients to vanish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w = z + 2y + 2x$. You will find that $\dot{w} = 0$ using your system. This implies that $w$ is constant for any solution. Notice that $w$ is a linear function of the coordinates $(x,y,z)$, and this means that the motion of the dynamical system is always orthogonal to the vector $(2,2,1)$ and hence reside in planes.

Comment: Great answer. How would we pedestrians know to look for such a function? How would we craft such a solution?

Comment: @dantopa: about 50% of the questions on MSE are exercise and homework questions. And it would be extremely annoying (as an instructor) to craft a first order dynamical system where every orbit is planar but different orbits can have different orientation. So I tried the simplest possible thing and it worked. (Sorry to disappoint!) // Had it not worked I would try to see if the orbits all lie in radial planes (so conservation of angle variable $\theta$ in cylindrical coordinate).

Comment: In the present case, one can *compute* the desired plane rather than guess it, see comment on main.

Comment: @did: the "guess" part refers to the ansatz that a linear combination of $x,y,z$ is stationary under the system. It is possible for a 3D dynamical system to have every orbit be planar without verifying this ansatz. (For example, $\dot{x_i} = x_i$.)

Comment: Understood. $ $